# Error in pyarrow while installing Apache Beam in Raspberry Pi

Tags: pip, raspberry-pi3, apache-beam

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and should be installing the Apache Beam SDK to connect it to Google Cloud Platform services such as Pub/Sub, Dataflow, and BigQuery. I've got Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) installed as my OS. I've been following the instructions very carefully on a community tutorial in GCP:

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ardu-pi-serial-part-2

Ran the following commands:

```html
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community.git
cd community/tutorials/ardu-pi-serial-part-2
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r beam-requirements.txt
pip install apache-beam[gcp]
```

Then I get the error while installing apache-beam:

```
creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7
  -- Running cmake for pyarrow
  cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/pi/community/tutorials/ardu-pi-serial-part-2/venv/bin/python2  -DPYARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /tmp/pip-install-L4MeVK/pyarrow
  unable to execute 'cmake': No such file or directory
  error: command 'cmake' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
  Building wheel for googledatastore (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for googledatastore: filename=googledatastore-7.0.2-py2-none-any.whl size=18154 sha256=d819df28a4cf473e25913fd34bb56506651a3c81b26d66fc2b6b3afede341f8d
  Stored in directory: /home/pi/.cache/pip/wheels/a6/07/b7/048bd604cfadf321bc995c1d2b6e92770bf852e2209b9dcc97
  Building wheel for proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1 (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1: filename=proto_google_cloud_datastore_v1-0.90.4-py2-none-any.whl size=23752 sha256=70834e2d3c64fdfbf04a6326b27b0ec85d01ffd408f15df7b0cefa055265c9b5
  Stored in directory: /home/pi/.cache/pip/wheels/80/86/e7/3e30f012839d7608dc34c5bb5087356307a028c7e1c44c3075
  Building wheel for grpc-google-iam-v1 (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for grpc-google-iam-v1: filename=grpc_google_iam_v1-0.12.3-py2-none-any.whl size=18500 sha256=0c5278ed422f0a616fdc3b54de4a750348441ce9f945cb0a1eaa2d5e9b7d94f3
  Stored in directory: /home/pi/.cache/pip/wheels/77/4d/90/443c1cecdcfbf9d97f6e567304aacddc234cf1b26e48c6f0e5
  Building wheel for googleapis-common-protos (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for googleapis-common-protos: filename=googleapis_common_protos-1.51.0-py2-none-any.whl size=77593 sha256=910992bfc3cf5b58189e21114ccc2c7bca83a91bedd02cdb06d8a2e783b97007
  Stored in directory: /home/pi/.cache/pip/wheels/56/af/44/f0c28e985bc224ffb90612f7cdeef432ba4fbd5d15485ab271
Successfully built apache-beam crcmod dill fastavro future hdfs httplib2 pymongo oauth2client avro pyvcf googledatastore proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1 grpc-google-iam-v1 googleapis-common-protos
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

What could be the reason this is happening and how would I fix this?

Comment: I'll try to reproduce your case on my Rpi and let you know - unless of course you already found a solution :) It would also be great if you edited your post and put in detail what steps/commands you did.

Comment: You might be interested to know of the existence of [Raspberry Pi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @W_B Thank you so much for this! I've edited the post about the steps I did. Still struggling and finding ways in solving this. I'm looking up on Docker and try to build pyarrow from there.
I deeply appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'll definitely take a look and post there as well. Thank you!

Comment: It's taking me more time to get my Rpi ready - hold on tight - I'm almost done and I will have some time on Sunday :)

Comment: @W_B Not a problem at all, thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: Any luck ? I will have my Rpi ready this evening for testing :)

Comment: None so far, still stuck on the error. I'll keep in touch if ever you find a solution, thanks again!